# How to draw gradient background in HTML or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, drawing

Is there an easy way to draw a gradient like what is pictured here?  Or would it be best to create an image?

[image]

I want it to be a square or rectangle, as pictured.

I would like to create multiple gradient backgrounds similar to this, but using different colors in each.

Additionally, I found [this website](http://gradients.glrzad.com/), which is really helpful, but not the control that I'm looking for.  I want a radial type of gradient, again like shown.

Suggestions?

Comment: [This site](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) includes radial gradients.

Comment: @PeterOlson, that is almost exactly what I was looking for.  Is there any way to make it start the radial gradient from a corner? I'm not seeing it, if so.

Comment: Never mind, I can just modify it manually. @PeterOlson Can you post that as an answer so I can mark the question answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This site](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) generates CSS gradients, including radial gradients.

Comment: For anyone else wanting to move the center of the circle, replace the "50% 50%" with "top left", etc.